# Cannot read JSON object returned from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending a JSON object to a PHP file, The PHP does some manipulation and returns a JSON string:

```
$('button#indexOpener').on('click', function() {
    var aUsername = $('input#edUsername').val();    
    var aPassword = $('input#edPassword').val();

    if (($.trim(aUsername) != '') && ($.trim(aPassword) != '')) {
        var str = $("#form_login :input").serializeArray();
        $.post("<?php echo URL; ?>ajax/checklogin", str, function(data) {
            alert(data.edUsername); 
        }); 
    }
    else {
        alert('Please insert a valid username and password');
        alert("<?php echo URL; ?>/ajax");   
    }
});
```

the PHP echoes a JSON object:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

but when I try to alert the data with jQuery:

```
function(data) {
  alert(data.edUsername);   
}
```

is displaying the message undefined. I am sure it is something stupid but I cannot see what I am doing wrong, can you help?

Comment: Have you checked the console, whether the data is actually returned? Also: Any errors on either client or server side?

Comment: try console.log(data) so you can see the whole structure

Comment: `$("#form_login :input").serializeArray();` Doesn't it should be like this: `$("#form_login").serializeArray();`

Comment: The console does not show any error. If I just alert(data) is returning {"edUsername":"qqq" "edPassword":"qqq"} but if I alert alert(data.edUsername); I get "undefined"? It is like the return object is not a JSON object but I am using echo json_encode($_POST); in my php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no dataType set for `$.post()`. jQuery will try to recognize returned content type, but you need to set correct headers. So, you need to add:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

before `echo json_encode`, or you should set dataType:"json" in JS code (fourth parameter of `$.post()`):

```
$.post("<?php echo URL; ?>ajax/checklogin", str, function(data) {
    alert(data.edUsername); 
}, "json");
```

This way, jQuery will know that the data returned is in JSON format and should be parsed. Without it, jQuery will check the `Content-Type` header and apply parser according to it. Suppose if no custom content type headers set, it will return return data as HTML. Actually, that is a usual string.

> If I just alert(data) is returning {"edUsername":"qqq"
>   "edPassword":"qqq"} but if I alert alert(data.edUsername); I get
>   "undefined"?

JSON is a regular string which should be parsed on client side. jQuery detects your response as plain text or HTML and does not parse JSON to Javascript object. In case of data being an object, you would get [object Object] in alert window.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it did not work. Thank you for replying though.

Comment: Please note that I made a mistake in header code initially. But now it is updated. Once you are getting json string in data, than the only problem is that jquery does not convert it to object. dataType:"json" and content-type header should fix that.

Comment: Sorry I misstyped the header, your solution works. Thank you everybody for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be this way using `$.getJSON()`:

```
var str = $("#form_login").serialize();

$.getJSON("<?php echo URL; ?>ajax/checklogin", {data:str}, function(data){
     alert(data.edUsername); 
});
```